# Create Individuals using Jena

Tags: java, rdf, jena, owl

I created an owl file using Jena:

```xml
<rdf:RDF xmlns="file:/D:/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl#"
 xml:base="file:/D:/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl"
 xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
 xmlns:diag="file:/D:/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl#"
 xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="file:/D:/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl"/>



<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&diag;hasSymptom">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&diag;Desease"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&diag;Symptom"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>


<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&diag;DesId">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&diag;Desease"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string"/>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>



<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&diag;DesLabel">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&diag;Desease"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string"/>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>


<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&diag;SympId">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&diag;Symptom"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string"/>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>


<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&diag;SympLabel">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&diag;Symptom"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string"/>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>




<owl:Class rdf:about="&diag;Desease"/>

<owl:Class rdf:about="&diag;Symptom"/>



<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Individuals
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->
```

I want to create individuals, this is my java code to create the ontModel:

```java
//******************************Create new Ontology*******************************************
    ontoDiag = modelDiag.createOntology(baseURI);

    modelDiag.setNsPrefix("diag", ns);

    //*****************Create Classes Desease && Symptoms ****************************************
    desease = modelDiag.createClass(ns + "Desease");
    symptom = modelDiag.createClass(ns + "Symptom");

    //*********************Create DataType Property label && id for symptom class***********************
    name = modelDiag.createDatatypeProperty(ns + "SympLabel");
    name.setDomain(symptom);
    name.setRange(XSD.xstring);
    id = modelDiag.createDatatypeProperty(ns + "SympId");
    id.setDomain(symptom);
    id.setRange(XSD.xstring);
    //*********************Create DataType Property label && id for desease class***********************
    nameDes = modelDiag.createDatatypeProperty(ns + "DesLabel");
    nameDes.setDomain(desease);
    nameDes.setRange(XSD.xstring);
    idDes = modelDiag.createDatatypeProperty(ns + "DesId");
    idDes.setDomain(desease);
    idDes.setRange(XSD.xstring);

    //*********************Create Object Property hasSymptom *******************************************
    hasSymptom = modelDiag.createObjectProperty(ns + "hasSymptom");
    hasSymptom.addDomain(desease);
    hasSymptom.addRange(symptom);
```

and this is the part where I create individuals

```
 //***********************************Create Individual Desease****************************

        Individual IndivDes = modelDiag.createIndividual(ns + desChoosen, desease);

        //***************add the property name to desease ************************************** 
        Literal desName = modelDiag.createTypedLiteral(desChoosen, XSDDatatype.XSDstring);
        Statement desNameSt = modelDiag.createStatement(IndivDes, name, desName);
        modelDiag.add(desNameSt);

        //***************add the property id to desease ************************************** 
        Literal desId = modelDiag.createTypedLiteral(IdDes, XSDDatatype.XSDstring);
        Statement desIdSt = modelDiag.createStatement(IndivDes, id, desId);
        modelDiag.add(desIdSt);
```

The code work perfectly, but the problem is the individuals created look like this:

```xml
<diag:Desease rdf:about="file:/D:/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl#orbital cyst">
<diag:hasSymptom>
  <diag:Symptom rdf:about="file:/D:/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl#severe chest pain">
    <diag:SympLabel>severe chest pain</diag:SympLabel>
  </diag:Symptom>
</diag:hasSymptom>
<diag:SympId>DES:000001</diag:SympId>
<diag:SympLabel>orbital cyst</diag:SympLabel>
```

instead:

```xml
 <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&diag;desease2">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&diag;Desease"/>
    <hasSymptom rdf:resource="&diag;pain2"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

I appreciate your help thank you..

Comment: What is the problem with that? The semantics is the same, the serialization is different. Any OWL parser will give you the same set of OWL axioms back...

Comment: I have got Errors when I open the file with Protege

Comment: How to you store the model with Jena. And which error do you get in Protege? We need more information, isn't that obvious? And why do you have white spaces in your URIs? Do you think this make sense?

Comment: There are no white spaces in the URIs, if you mean:    <diag:Desease rdf:about="file:/D:/onto/owl_ontologies/diagnostic.owl#orbital cyst">
after the # this is a String that I get it from another owl file.

Comment: I stored the model in a OWL file, and I opened it by Protege

Comment: ... do you read what I write? **How** do you store the data with Jena -> I mean the code obviously. And **what is the error** you get in Protege? And indeed there is a white space in the URI, or what do you think is the character between "orbit‌​al" and "cyst" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add explicitly rdf:type=owl:NamedIndividual:

```
public static void main(String ... strings) {
    OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
    m.setNsPrefix("test", "http://test#");
    Individual i = m.createIndividual("http://test#indi", m.createResource("http://test#cl"));
    i.addProperty(RDFS.comment, "something");
    i.addRDFType(OWL2.NamedIndividual);
    m.write(System.out);
}
```

This snippet will produce following rdf-xml:

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:test="http://test#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://test#indi">
    <rdfs:comment>something</rdfs:comment>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://test#cl"/>
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>
```

while without "i.addRDFType(OWL.NamedIndividual)" the output would be following:

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:test="http://test#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
  <test:cl rdf:about="http://test#indi">
    <rdfs:comment>something</rdfs:comment>
  </test:cl>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Note: owl:NamedIndividual is OWL2 declaration. there is no such thing in OWL1. jena does not support OWL2, although there is a vocabulary class for it (see org.apache.jena.vocabulary.OWL2)